# Moving subject picture

Tags: blur, motion-blur

Can anyone please explain me how to achieve this kind of pictures?

[link](http://www.google.be/imgres?imgurl=https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-EIAXF4yG8TY/TYioBVzJOeI/AAAAAAAAAmo/CZIjNTcZifQ/s1600/65.jpg&imgrefurl=http://all-informationz.blogspot.com/2011/03/photography-and-great-outdoors.html&h=516&w=800&sz=164&tbnid=o9oELnjucwStHM:&tbnh=88&tbnw=136&zoom=1&usg=__1JbbqCPzHYyS9e5kR6OJ-p1_Wxs=&docid=-ojDqH2AGZpcOM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_axiUaXrN8So0AXe1oD4Bg&ved=0CFcQ9QEwDA&dur=3663)

Comment: Please see http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions

Comment: I agree with @mattdm - this question really needs some improvement in its structure and content.

Comment: it was already answered, for people like me who doesnt know the technical terms, then the best way to ask its with an example. there is no other way to ask if you dont even know the technical terms

Comment: @Luis: no, not necessarily. Please read the post I linked again. The example picture helps, but please find some way to describe what you see in the example. Even something like "sharp picture of a moving subject but the background is blurred" would be helpful. In this case Nir successfully read your mind and guessed that this is what you want, but it's often the case that we can't make that guess successfully. (Plus, how will someone else who doesn't know the technical terms ever find this in the future?)

Comment: In fact, if you had started with a more precise description, the website would very likely have automatically identified the existing question that asks almost exactly the same thing with a different example. But that only works if both people take a stab at the description. It doesn't have to be perfect, but the effort really makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a technique called "panning"

Basically, you use a long exposure (length depending on subject speed) and move the camera with the subject so the subject stays at the same location in the frame when you move.

Comment: According to mattdm, you sir are a mind reader! Hahah awesome!